# What wireless remote can be used for a Fujifilm S9900?

Tags: remote, wireless

What wireless remote can be used for a Fujifilm S9900? I am looking to see what wireless remote would be best.

Comment: Did this camera even provide wireless remote? 

Product specification page (http://www.fujifilm.com/products/digital_cameras/s/finepix_s9900w/specifications/)  says: Wireless function
* Only for FinePix S9900W: 
Geotagging / Wireless communication (Image transfer) / View & Obtain Images / Remote camera shooting / PC Autosave

Comment: Would it be the wireless app that I can connect to my phone instead of an actual wireless remote?

Comment: If there is an (probably free) app, why do you want get an extra device?
Don't get me wrong. I have a cam with snapbridge (wifi controll via app) and I love this option, because i had not to buy a extra (often pricey) device, that i can forget at home.

But to be honest, I don't fully understand your whole sentience since english is not my mother tongue.

Comment: @Horitsu There is also the disadvantage that using the phone as a wireless remote reduces the battery life of the phone. Some folks might prefer a separate device with its own batteries to preserve the life of the phone battery, particularly if they are in a remote area with little or no phone coverage for extended periods of time.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the user manual, it appears that the S9900's only wireless shutter capability is through a wifi connection and the Fuji smart device app.

The camera itself has no shutter release port, which is required for most 3rd-party add-on radio shutter triggers (you connect the radio receiver to the shutter release port, and use the transmitter in hand as your remote. Without the port, there's nothing to connect to).  And there's no optical wireless release capability built into the camera, either, such as Canon dSLRs have.

You may want to consider using the camera's self-timer instead.